# Recursive feature elimination with cross validation for regression in scikit-learn

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, wrapper, rfe

I want to apply a wrapper-method like Recursive Feature Elimination on my regression problem with scikit-learn. [Recursive feature elimination with cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py) gives a good overview, how to tune the number of features automatically.

I tried this:

```
modelX = LogisticRegression()
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=modelX, step=1, scoring='mean_absolute_error')
rfecv.fit(df_normdf, y_train)
print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)

# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of correct classifications)")
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()`
```

but I receive an error message like

```
`The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too few. 
The minimum number of labels for any class cannot be less than n_folds=3. % (min_labels, self.n_folds)), Warning)
```

The warning sounds like I have a classification problem, but my task is a regression problem. What can I do to get a result and what's wrong?

Comment: Wan you show us your `y_train` ?

Comment: My y_train has 1 column and ~10.000 rows with values between 1 and 200.

Comment: Are the values integers ? If so I think that it considers it as a multiclass classification problem. Try to cast the values to floats.

Comment: This make sense. I've casted the values to floats but the same warning occurs.

Comment: I got it now, i'll try to right an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happened :

By default, when the number of folds is not indicated by the user, the **Cross-Validation** of the `RFE` uses a `3-fold` cross-validation. So far so good.

**However**, if you look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html), it also uses `StartifiedKFold` which ensures that the folds are created by preserving the percentage of samples for each class. Therefore, since it seems (according to the error) that some elements of your output `y` are **unique**, they cannot be at the same time in 3 different folds. It throws an error !

The error comes from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a5ab948/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L577).

You need then to use unstratified K-fold : `KFold`.

The documentation of `RFECV` says that:
`"If the estimator is a classifier or if y is neither binary nor multiclass, sklearn.model_selection.KFold is used."`